# CAML Query where X =(A && B && C && D)

Tags: caml-query, caml

CAML makes me sad some days. Can someone point me in the right direction for the syntax in regards to a CAML query that would evaluate where X= A&B&C&D. My nesting is all off i'm assuming.

```
<Where>
<And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" /><Value Type="Text">A</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="Region" /><Value Type="Text">B</Value></Eq>
<And>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="BagVal" /><Value Type="Text">C</Value></Eq>
<Eq><FieldRef Name="SumVal" /><Value Type="Text">D</Value></Eq>
</And>
</And>
</Where>
```

Comment: For future reference, you can use a tool like CAML Query builder (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/458008/CAML-Query-Builder) to build error-prone CAML queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's your nesting. Try this:

```
<Where>
  <And>
    <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" /><Value Type="Text">A</Value></Eq>
    <And>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="Region" /><Value Type="Text">B</Value></Eq>
      <And>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name="BagVal" /><Value Type="Text">C</Value></Eq>
        <Eq><FieldRef Name="SumVal" /><Value Type="Text">D</Value></Eq>
      </And>
    </And>
  </And>
</Where>
```

You are not allowed to put more than two conditions in a single condition group.